# A problem about connected components‘ image under onto and continous map

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, continuity, connectedness

Here is a problem on *Topoloy* written by Marco Manetti, page89, question 5.4.

> Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be an identification. Show that if the connected components of $X$ are open, so are the connected components of $Y$.

I think that if we can prove that $A$ is a connected components of $Y$ implies $f^{-1}(A)$ can written as several connected components of $X$, then this problem can be solved. When I tried to prove it, I found that even if $f$ is just a onto and continous, this conclusion still holds. Here is my proof.

> If $B\subset X$ is a connected component, since $f$ is continous, then $f(B)$ is connected, hence contained in some connected component of $Y$. Because $f$ is onto, each pre-image of connected components of $Y$ can be written as several connected components of $X$.

My question is, can we replace the *identification* by *onto and continous* in this problem?

Comment: What is an identification?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos From the text: "A continuous surjective map $f:X\to Y$ is called an **identification** if the open sets of $Y$ are precisely the subsets $A\subset Y$ such that $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $X$."

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $f$ is an identification if $f$ is a onto and continous map, and $f^{-1}(A)$ open  implies $A$ open.

Comment: Your proof is a bit confusing. You define $B$ but then go on to use $A$. Okay, I see that you have edited it. Thanks.

Comment: @Math1000 Sorry, I have edited my proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, the claim is not true if you replace $f$ by continuous and onto.

The problem is the fact that **you still need to show that the image of open is open**, continuity does not satisfies.

Consider the following example: pick $Y$ to be any topological space whose components are NOT open. Pick $X$ to be the same set, equipped with the discrete topology.

Define $f :X \to Y$ to be $f(x)=x$. Then $f$ is continuous, onto, the components of $X$ are open, but the components of $Y$ are not.

**P.S.** An alternate approach for the problem is the following: Let $\{ C_i \}_{i}$ be the components of $X$ and $\{ D_j \}_j$ the components of $Y$.

You know that for each $i$ there exists some $j$ such that $f(C_i) \subset D_j$. Use this together with ontoness to show that for each $j$ you have 
$$f^{-1}(D_j) = \bigcup_{f(C_i) \subseteq D_j} C_i $$

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. I had a feeling this claim was not true but did not know how to show it. +1

Comment: Oh I know. My proof only shows that if $B \subset Y$ is a connected component, then $f^{-1}(B)$ is open. $f$ is an identification makes sure that $B$ is open. Thanks a lot!